# How to generate an ASCII representation of a Unix file hierarchy?

Tags: filesystems, visualization, ascii

all. I'm looking for a quick and dirty way to generate some diagrams of some directories that have almost, but not exactly, the same hierarchy, so I can show them around at a meeting and we can decide which flavor we like best. I'm not interested in the "leaf" nodes, just the directories.

The catch: I don't want to mess with X. This is a server system I deal with entirely through SSH. So I'm looking for something that will do ASCII layout, maybe with simple pipes-and-hyphens for lines or something.

Does anyone know of such a utility? I'm sure I could write something myself, but it's such a fiddly little sort of project, with handling spacing and layout and such; I'd really like to discover that someone's done it for me. Alas, Google doesn't seem to know of such a thing...or if it does, it's hidden beneath heaps of excellent visual explications of the standard general Unix file hierarchy. Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I would use [`tree`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree).

```
$ tree -d /usr|head -n 12
/usr
|-- X11R6
|   `-- lib
|       `-- X11
|           `-- wily
|-- bin
|   `-- X11 -> .
|-- games
|-- i586-mingw32msvc
|   |-- bin
|   |-- include
|   |   |-- GL
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. It's amazing how hard it is (at least for me) to find the simple little stuff in Unix sometimes. man -k directory didn't do it -- but man -k directories would have. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jenn: That's why I use a common root portion of a word for that kind of query `apropos director` (or `man -k director`) will find both. It works to include various prefixes as well: `apropos known` finds "known", "unknown" and "well-known".

Comment: And `tree` also works on Windows.

Comment: Using `tree` (version 1.5.3) I get some unicode characters to make the diagram look prettier. To get only ascii characters, I had to use `tree --charset ascii`

Comment: Not directly related, but there's also [`pstree`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?pstree+1). Tree is one of those programs like `top`; there are a number of fun variants.

Comment: Works just fine on Mac also, `brew install tree` first.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have tree you could use this linux/unix command:

```
ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'
```

You can also make a shell script see  [details here.](http://www.centerkey.com/tree/)

Explanation for the above command:

**`ls -R`** list all directories, sub-directories,

Explanation
`ls -R`  list all the file and directories recursively

ex:

```
./sys/devices/platform/ag71xx.0/net/eth0:
addr_assign_type  device            iflink            speed


./sys/devices/platform/ag71xx.0/net/eth0/queues:
tx-0
```

**`grep ":$"`** filters only the files that have `:` before line end,
    thus remains, something like.

```
./sys/devices/platform/ag71xx.0/net/eth0:
./sys/devices/platform/ag71xx.0/net/eth0/queues:
```

Then a series of multiple command are passed using `-e` switch to `sed`

**`'s/:$//'`** strips all the trailin `:`

**`'s/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g'`** leaves only what is between `/` `-` and replace each with `--`

the rest two command add a few spaces and a `|`

The result is something like:

```
   |-----------eth0
   |-------------queues
```

Comment: +1 for effort, -1 because you didn't explain the regex. I can be swayed to upvote if an explanation is forthcoming... (I know regexes, and you know regexes, but a lot of people find them frightening)

Comment: @ParthianShot I tried and I added explanation